# Two front end exchange servers one back end server topology?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

I am trying to setup a second front end server in a network using exchange 2003. So far I am able to get it to work at least partially as when I access OWA on this server I can view messages; however, when I try to send or create any new folder I am unable to do so. I have already confirmed that this is not due   javascript or popups being blocked. Can anyone shed light on where I may have gone wrong with this?

Comment: (It's 2014... and you're still trying to support/enhance a 2003 installation?)

Comment: The first place you're going wrong is in using Exchange 2003 still. As for anything else, you might try sharing what happens when you try to create a new folder.

Comment: I know that using exchange 2003 is not a good decision. However, it is not my decision whether or not to upgrade (apparently the company doesn't want to).

Comment: As for creating a new folder or sending a message OWA does nothing when I click on these which seems strange since I used the same configuration in this server as the first front-end server. It seems that the OWA from this server is lacking full functionality.

Comment: I still think it's a really bad choice, and browser compatibility is one big reason why, but oh well. Have you applied KB911829? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15917

Comment: Sadly my superiors only see that they are saving money by not having to purchase a newer software and I will see about downloading the update.